# New to databases - is my idea safe to use?

Tags: php, mysql, json, database

I've never really worked with databases before, and I never had any courses regarding it. Now, I would like to have a website that saves users together with some data about the users.

My initial instinct is to save the data in a JSON file, write some scripts in php that request certain parts of that data (and the data is easily readable since php can just parse the JSON). If possible, I'd put the JSON file somewhere other than inside the `public_html` folder, so it's not accessible to the public, but I'm not sure if it is even possible for php to read it if that's the case. Otherwise, I might set the file to not be accessible for the public, but in the same folder as the php scripts (or close to that), but I have no idea how secure that is.

I know mysql exists, but since there is some amount of time pressure on the project, I'd prefer to use languages that I do know (JSON for the database and PHP and javascript for the scripts). That way, I know what's happening and I understand everything instead of trying to understand a whole new concept. I'm aware mysql is not a difficult language to learn, but I'd want to understand what happens behind the scenes as well, and besides, I'm not even quite sure if the server that the project will be running on has mysql installed.

In short, is creating a database in a JSON file a good, safe, way to create a database? Or am I much better off learning mysql?

Comment: One of the big problems with any web app is that if you have more than 1 person accessing the web pages at the same time, JSON has no method of ensuring the data is kept consistent.  Using a database is worth the effort.

Comment: @NigelRen PHP has the flock() function for file locking. But I agree with you that it would well be worth the effort for the OP to learn about databases.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson but `flock()` effectively turns it into a single user system.

Comment: @NigelRen No, not single-user, but single-threaded. I said I agreed with you that a database is the way to go. But of course, when you update a row in a table, that is a form of locking (and thus single-threading) also, isn't it?

Comment: @RonaldAaronson yes, but it doesn't stop other users updating other rows simultaneously. Whereas if you have a single JSON file containing the whole dataset then only one user can write to that file at a time, which will become an enormous bottleneck (as will parsing and querying it). If you go for different files for different bits of the dataset then it reduces that issue but at the cost of fragmenting the data even more. I'm sure you know all that...but the row locking Vs file locking is one (of many) crucial advantage of a database

Comment: Don't focus on MySQL alone. There's a variety of databases out there, some relational, some not, all of which have their use cases. JSON is not a database, it's a data *serialization format*. Remember that with programming you tend to get a lot more out of your learning than the time you invest in it, but if you invest zero time you get zero return. If you spend some time understanding relational databases, for example, you'll have a powerful tool you can use to solve problems far more complex than "a bunch of JSON files" can ever handle.